# Live template for starting activity in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

Is there a live template for starting activity in Android studio that generates the code needed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the live template:

```
Intent intent = new Intent($ACTIVITY$.this, );
startActivity(intent);
```

Abbreviation that I use is `starta`.